# Spring & Maven - how to provide custom properties to Spring application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a Spring application which runs in a web container (Tomcat). This Spring application uses a properties file to find the database JDBC location:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class MyApplication {
}
```

In app.properties, I have:

```
database.dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app
```

It's now easy to get the value at runtime:

```
@Component
class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Value("${database.dataSource.url}")
    private String URL;
}
```

So far, so good. Now I am using the `cargo-maven2-plugin` plugin to deploy the WAR during an integration test. Before the WAR is deployed, an ad-hoc PostgreSQL database is deployed into a Docker container via the `docker-maven-plugin` plugin. This instance runs on a custom, dynamic port instead of the usual 5432. This port is filled in into the `${database.port}` property by the `docker-maven-plugin` plugin.

This means that I need to somehow alter `app.properties` on the fly to fill in this port. This seems hacky, so maybe there is a way to provide/override the port via the `cargo-maven2-plugin` to my Spring application, so I could use that one instead of the one in `app.properties`?

What is a 'clean' way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @TestPropertySource to use a different properties file for testing. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html